# Getting exception when converting utc format DateTime string to date time

Tags: .net, string, date, time, utc

Getting exception when converting UTC format DateTime string to date time

Run-time exception (line 16): String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Stack Trace:

[System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
at Program.Main() :line 16

```
    string launchMeetingDate = "2020-10-27T09.29.00.000Z";
    var launchDate = Helper.ConvertStringToUTCDateTime(launchMeetingDate);
    public static DateTime ConvertStringToUTCDateTime(string date)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        bool isDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(date, out dateTime);
        return dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
    }
```

Comment: What format parameters are you passing to the method in line 16 of your code?

Comment: I am trying to convert DateTimeString = "2020-10-27T09.29.00.000Z" to date time

Comment: Yes, you already said so in the question, and that's the first parameter, but what are the other 2 parameter values (`format` and `provider`)? Without know the `format`, how did you expect us to help you figure out what you did wrong?

Comment: I am saving date time in "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000'Z'" format in the database as a string and now trying to parse it to utc date time.

Comment: Any particular reason you're refusing to tell us what the other parameter values are, e.g. by *showing us the code* of line 16 (and before)? If you don't want to provide the necessary information needed for us to answer, why did you ask this question?

Comment: Before Saving in database:

Helper.ConvertDateTimeToUTCString(company, meetingAttendiesModel.meetingTimeRecordVM.launchMeetingDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000'Z'");

Comment: public static DateTime ConvertDateTimeToUTCString(Company company, string date)
{ string companyTimeZone = company.defaultTimeZone;
 string stringDate = date;
 var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(stringDate, null);
TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(companyTimeZone);
 DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTimeOffset.DateTime, tst);
return result;
}

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the help in advance, sorry I misunderstood your first comment,

Comment: During getting from database:
var launchDate = Helper.ConvertStringToUTCDateTime(launchMeetingDate); 
 public static DateTime ConvertStringToUTCDateTime(string date)
        {
                DateTime dateTime;
                bool isDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(date, out dateTime);
                    return dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
        }

Comment: @Andreas are you there?

Comment: Don't show code in comments. **Edit** the question and show code there, well-formatted for human readability.

Comment: Sure, let me update, and thanks for your support.

Comment: The error in the question shows that the error is in a call to `System.DateTime.ParseExact()` in line 16 of your `Program.Main()` method. None of the code you showed in comments has the `ParseExact()` call, so what's the purpose of showing all that code? We need to see the `ParseExact()` call to help you figure out what you did wrong. Please, show at least a little common sense, and **show the relevant code**!! I mean, If you want our help, that is. Do you?

Comment: @NikhilKumar - You've accepted an answer that doesn't actually answer your question. Can you please not do that?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, I have found that it was a wrong entry in my database, and now no need to replace,  Actually it was an issue at my end and now I fixed it but it would be good if we found any solution for this situation.

Comment: @NikhilKumar - It's simple - you parse with the exact pattern. If you have two patterns you try both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try This

```
DateTimeString = "2020-10-27T09:29:00.000Z"
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working but how we can replace '.' with ':' for all records?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's close. @Akash can you please put the in the code required to show the OP how to parse his particular date format?